# linked list using double pointers

Tags: c

Using double pointers first time to create and display linked list

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node * next;
};
void Insert(struct node **, int , int );
void display(struct node *);
int main()
{
    int c, data, position;
    struct node* head;
    do{
        printf("Enter a choice :\n");
        printf("1. Add an element.\n");
        printf("2. Del an element.\n3.Display List.\n");
        printf("4.Delete linked list.\n5.Exit.\n");
        printf("Your Choice :");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        switch(c){
            case 1 :
                printf("\nEnter data and position :\n");
                scanf("%d %d",&data,&position);
                Insert(&head,data,position);
                break;
            case 2 :

                break;
            case 3 :
                printf("Linked List : \n");
                display(head);
                break;
            case 4 :

                break;
            case 5 :
                exit(0);
            default :
                printf("Invalid Choice.\n");
                break;
        }
    }while(1);

    return 0;
}


void Insert(struct node **ptrhead, int item, int position){
    struct node *p,*newnode;
    //node creation.
    newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (!newnode)
    {
        printf("Memory Error.\n");
        return;
    }
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->data = item;

    p = *ptrhead;

    // Creates initial node
    if (!(p->data))
        {
            p = newnode;
        }

    // insertion at beginning
    if (position==1)
    {
            newnode->next = p;
            p = newnode;
            free(newnode);
    }
    // insertionn at middle or end.
    else
    {
        int i=1;
        while(p->next!=NULL && i<position-1){
            p=p->next;
            i++;
        }
        newnode->next = p->next;
        p->next = newnode;
    }

    *ptrhead = p;

};

// Display Linked list
void display(struct node *head){
    if (head)
    {
        do{
            printf("%d\n", head->data);
            head = head->next;
        }while(head->next);
    }

};
```

I will add functions for deletion and other operations later. Right now , I just want to insert and display fns to work . But output comes as infinitely running loop with wrong values. I cannot figure out what's wrong in my code , please help ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your title includes *double-pointers*. When working on your linked list, understand why the `insert` and `delete_node` require passing the address of the list as a parameter rather than just a pointer to the list. The reason it is required in the two cases is to enable adding or removing a new first node which will change the address of your list. What would happen if you inserted a new first node, but only passed `node *ptrhead` to the `insert` function? (note: you can delete the entire list without passing the address of the list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why somebody would be writing this type of C today, looks like maybe I'm doing your homework for you... In any case, you asked to fix your code, not rewrite it, so here's the minimum set of changes.

`head` should be initialized to `NULL`.

`if (!(p->data))` is not right.  That if statement should just be:

```
// Creates initial node
if (!p)
{
    *ptrhead = newnode;
    return;
}
```

Remove `free(newnode);`.

The insert at middle/end code could be

```
int i = 1;
struct node *n = p;
while (n->next != NULL && i<position - 1){
    n = n->next;
    i++;
}
newnode->next = n->next;
n->next = newnode;
```

The final `insert` function:

```
void Insert(struct node **ptrhead, int item, int position)
{
    struct node *p, *newnode;
    //node creation.
    newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (!newnode)
    {
        printf("Memory Error.\n");
        return;
    }
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->data = item;

    p = *ptrhead;

    // Creates initial node
    if (!p)
    {
        *ptrhead = newnode;
        return;
    }

    // insertion at beginning
    if (position == 1)
    {
        newnode->next = p;
        p = newnode;
    }
    // insertionn at middle or end.
    else
    {
        int i = 1;
        struct node *n = p;
        while (n->next != NULL && i<position - 1){
            n = n->next;
            i++;
        }
        newnode->next = n->next;
        n->next = newnode;
    }

    *ptrhead = p;

}
```

Your `print` function isn't quite right, just make it:

```
// Display Linked list
void display(struct node *head)
{
    while (head)
    {
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious -- why would somebody not be writing a linked list in C like this -- today?

Comment: You could just use the C++ Standard Library.  There isn't much reason not to use C++, even if you don't use an stl container.

Comment: Well, there are some reasons people choose [**C as a matter of choice**](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57918) `:)`

Comment: Thanks Rob L, for answering point-wise. BUT I can't understand why I can't write "p= newnode" instead of " *ptrhead = newnode "   in    " // Creating Initial node" portion.

Comment: You could have done p = newnode, but then the next if would have needed to be "else if".  If you are really wanting to use pure legacy C, then you were probably taught to have a single point of return from your functions. In that case, you might want the else if.